# Binary operator '&&' cannot be applied to two Bool operands

Tags: beta, swift2, xcode7

I recently updated Xcode to the new 7.0 beta.

I did the migration with the assistant but there are a few more issues.

```
func saveContext () {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save() {
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

On line 4 there are 4 issues:
the first one is:

> Binary operator '&&' cannot be applied to two Bool operands

the second one is:

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Can someone please help me?

Comment: This question has a much better title than does the duplicate, as programmers are likely to google on this confusing error message. For reference, the following declaration gives the same error message:     func test() {
        return true && true
    }  ,  Notice that the function is declared as void , i.e. ->Bool is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code that should do the trick. Remember to preceed throw statements with try and catch them.

```
func saveContext () {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
        if moc.hasChanges  {
            do {
                try moc.save()
            } catch {
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(error)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get following error now: "Type 'ErrorType.Protocol' does not conform to protocol 'ErrorType'"

Comment: I edited the code. Can you try with the latest update?

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please consider approving my answer if things are satisfying for you.

Comment: This is not a criticism of your answer.  Where does `error` come from?  It's weird that when they converted to the `throws` syntax, the `error` isn't explicity mentioned, but it's still there apparently.

Comment: @vacawama: A plain `catch` is a shortcut for `catch let error` if I remember correctly.

Comment: Yep, I used the shortcut. This acts like a 'default' in 'switch' and the syntax is nifty.